# Does Kde Connect has a limit to file sending?

Tags: file-sharing, kde-connect

I'm trying to send an ISO file from my phone (Nexus 5) to my desktop, the progress bar on my phone gets completed but the file doesn't get available in my desktops `/download` folder. while small image files and audios can get transferred, it's not a space problem cause I've plenty of space in my `/home` partition. So is their is transfer limit to Kde Connect?

---

I'm using Kde Connect on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04, I've heard that it doesn't work well without Kde Desktop, and also if their are other apps that i can use to transfer a 1.6Gb file, suggest that as well

Comment: Is a USB connection not an option? At 1.6Gb, it would likely be much faster, even if you spent 5 minutes looking for a cable. Plus, you wouldn't take the hit in spent battery power. I second the AirDroid answer for wireless connections.

Comment: @b_laoshi that's the problem, for some reason my USB cable's are just charging the phone, and not connecting in file transfer, I think it's an issue with the Micro USB port in phone

Comment: i played with kdeconnect a while ago and abandoned it in favor of a samba share on the workstation.  many android file managers will handle basic samba shares easily, and i found them much more convenient for selecting and sending multiple files than kdeconnect.

Comment: @quixotic I really wanted an answer like this, could you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used KDE Connect, but [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) has worked for me in the past when I needed to transfer large files from my phone to my PC. It's pretty intuitive to use:

1. Install AirDroid on your phone.
2. Open the app on your phone and make a note of the URL shown on screen.
3. Connect your phone and Linux device to the same wireless network.
4. Open your preferred browser on the PC and navigate to the URL provided by the app.
5. Click to connect and you're ready to transfer files.

You can also connect by scanning a QR code on the PC from your phone, as explained in [this](https://www.linux.com/blog/airdroid-transfer-files-between-android-phonestablets-and-linux-any-distribution) post (although I haven't used this method myself).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about KDE Connect.

Comment: @user598527 No, it doesn't answer the bit about KDE Connect, but it does answer the final part: "... "*and also if their* [sic] *are other apps that i can use to transfer a 1.6Gb file, suggest that as well*" (which, I assume, is why the OP accepted the answer).